# Get parent OU of user in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to check, if a a user is in a specific parent OU.

How can I do that?

Check below code for a clear desciption of what I am looking for.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public bool IsUserInOU(string samAccountName, string OUName){

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName))
            {                    
                //Check if the user is in the OU specified in OUName
                //Something like:
                //return user.IsInOU(OUName);
            }
         }
}

public void TestIt_1(){
  //The parent OU of this user is "AwesomeOU"
  string samAccountName = "Joe";
  string OUName = "AwesomeOU";
  bool expected = true;
  bool actual = IsUserInOU(samAccountName, OUName);
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

public void TestIt_2(){
  //The parent OU of this user is "WhateverOU"
  string samAccountName = "Mike";
  string OUName = "AwesomeOU";
  bool expected = false;
  bool actual = IsUserInOU(samAccountName, OUName);
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

The Domain:

- National OU

  - Awesome OU

    - Joe
  - Whatever OU

    - Mike

## Solution 1 after empi's answer

With the information given by empi, I wrote the below method to extract the first OU in the DistinguishedName. Having done that, the rest is a breeze.

```
public static string GetOUForUser(string samAccountName)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName))
            {
                //System.Console.WriteLine(user.DistinguishedName);
                int startIndex = user.DistinguishedName.IndexOf("OU=", 1) + 3; //+3 for  length of "OU="
                int endIndex = user.DistinguishedName.IndexOf(",", startIndex);
                var group = user.DistinguishedName.Substring((startIndex), (endIndex - startIndex));
                return group;
            }
        }
    }
```

## Solution 2 after JPBlanc's answer

```
public static string GetOUForUser(string samAccountName)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName))
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry deUser = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry)
                {
                    using (DirectoryEntry deUserContainer = deUser.Parent)
                    {
                        return deUserContainer.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work if objects have commas in their distinguished name.  You need to handle the way those are escaped, or use JPBlanc's Solution 2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok @Empi solution is working, but `UserPrincipal` is built on `DirectoryEntry` objects that provides a `parent` or `container` properties that just give you the object you are looking for, without using string way.

```
/* Retreiving a principal context
 */
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WM2008R2ENT:389", "dc=dom,dc=fr", "dom\\jpb", "MyPwd");

/* Retreive a user
 */
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "user1");

/* Retreive the container
 */
DirectoryEntry deUser = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
DirectoryEntry deUserContainer = deUser.Parent;
Console.WriteLine (deUserContainer.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

This information is in [UserPrincipal.DistinguishedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.distinguishedname.aspx). You should check if DistinguishedName ends with "," + ou distinguished name (case insensitive). However, you must know the distingushed name of ou you're checking.

For example, if dn is: `CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM`, then it says that user is in `OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM` ou.

Comment: That is one step further, thanks! I can string-hack my way to a solution now, but it would seem there should be a nicer way.

Comment: As far as I know it's not a hack. It's just how directory services work. If you were given a file path and you should check if file is in some directory you would do the same thing.

Comment: This test is incorrect for nested OUs.  e.g. if user is CN=Jeff,OU=Sales,OU=North...then you 'test' for OU=North, you'll get a positive, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would get the Distinguished Name for a specific AD user, hope it helps :-)

```
private static string GetDNOfUser(string user)
{
    var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environmentals.Domain, Environmentals.OUPath);

    //Creating object for search filter
    UserPrincipal userPrin = new UserPrincipal(ctx)
    {
        //Only getting users with the same name as the input
        Name = user
    };

    var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher
    {
        //Applying filter to query
        QueryFilter = userPrin
    };

    //Finding the user
    var results = searcher.FindOne();
    searcher.Dispose();

    //Return the distinguishedname
    return results.DistinguishedName;
}
```